# Missing values replaced with average of its neighbors (timeseries)

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I want all missing values from dataset to replace with average of two nearest neighbors. Except of first and last cells and when neighbors are 0 (then I manually fix values). I coded this and it works, but the solution is not very smart. Is is another way to do it faster? Interpolate method is suitable for that? I'm not quite sure how does it work.

Input:

```
         0       1       2       3       4       5
0      0.0  1596.0  1578.0  1567.0  1580.0  1649.0
1   1554.0  1506.0     0.0  1466.0  1469.0  1503.0
2   1588.0  1510.0  1495.0  1485.0  1489.0     0.0
3   1592.0     0.0     0.0  1571.0  1647.0     0.0
```

Output:

```
         0       1       2       3       4       5
0      0.0  1596.0  1578.0  1567.0  1580.0  1649.0
1   1554.0  1506.0  1486.0  1466.0  1469.0  1503.0
2   1588.0  1510.0  1495.0  1485.0  1489.0  1540.5
3   1592.0     0.0     0.0  1571.0  1647.0     0.0
```

Code:

```
data_len = len(df)
first_col = str(df.columns[0])
last_col = str(df.columns[len(df.columns) - 1])

d = df.apply(lambda s: pd.to_numeric(s, errors="coerce"))
m = d.eq(0) | d.isna()
s = m.stack()
list = s[s].index.tolist() #list of indeces of missing values
count = len(list)

for el in list:
    if (el == ('0', first_col) or el == (str(data_len - 1), last_col)):
        continue
    next = df.at[str(int(el[0]) + 1), first_col] if el[1] == last_col else df.at[el[0], str(int(el[1]) + 1)]
    prev = df.at[str(int(el[0]) - 1), last_col] if el[1] == first_col else df.at[el[0], str(int(el[1]) - 1)]
    if prev == 0 or next == 0:
        continue
    df.at[el[0],el[1]] = (prev + next)/2
```

JSON of example:

```
{"0":{"0":0.0,"1":1554.0,"2":1588.0,"3":0.0},"1":{"0":1596.0,"1":1506.0,"2":1510.0,"3":0.0},"2":{"0":1578.0,"1":0.0,"2":1495.0,"3":1561.0},"3":{"0":1567.0,"1":1466.0,"2":1485.0,"3":1571.0},"4":{"0":1580.0,"1":1469.0,"2":1489.0,"3":1647.0},"5":{"0":1649.0,"1":1503.0,"2":0.0,"3":0.0}}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *then I manually fix values*? Should they be ignored then?

Comment: I must analyze what happened to the data so I don't want to process it with python code.

Comment: I left this code. Probably better solution would be stack all values to Serie and then apply yatu's answer and at the end slice back to proper format.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach using [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) to average the neighbour's values and slice assigning back to the dataframe:

```
m = df==0
r = (df.shift(axis=1)+df.shift(-1,axis=1))/2
df.iloc[1:-1,1:-1] = df.mask(m,r)
```

---

```
print(df)

        0       1       2       3       4       5
0     0.0  1596.0  1578.0  1567.0  1580.0  1649.0
1  1554.0  1506.0  1486.0  1466.0  1469.0  1503.0
2  1588.0  1510.0  1495.0  1485.0  1489.0     0.0
3     0.0     0.0  1561.0  1571.0  1647.0     0.0
```

Comment: Smart way! I didn't know about that. However I wrongly specified what edge cell means. It's only [0,0] and [3,5]. And it computes average when neighbor equals 0.